# Ubuntu apt upgrades increasing and getting skipped

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I've been using ubuntu as my daily driver for a while already (since version 18 LTS). It's very useful and I personally love it.

I've recently installed ubuntu desktop 22.04.1 LTS on a brand new computer (last saturday 1/28/2023).

The first couple of days went fine, as expected. Installed a few tools from a variety of ways:

- Zip/targz files (unpack, set permissions and use it)
- snap (usually from ubuntu software gui)
- apt (from terminal commands)

As usual, when prompted by ubuntu software update gui, I apply available updates.

I also run "sudo apt update" command from terminal. If upgrades are available, I tipically run "sudo apt upgrade" to apply available upgrades and, eventually, run "sudo apt autoremove" to remove any unused packages left.

Up until ubuntu 20 LTS, this was going smoothly. No problems at all.

But with ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, upgrades are not only increasing but also being skipped from the upgrade process as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]   
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease              
Hit:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99,8 kB]
Get:7 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]
Get:8 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [265 kB]
Get:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,6 kB]
Fetched 703 kB in 4s (181 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
28 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
gnome-control-center-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 all [upgradable from: 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5]
gnome-control-center-faces/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 all [upgradable from: 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5]
gnome-control-center/jammy-updates 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5]
gnome-initial-setup/jammy-updates 42.0.1-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.0.1-1ubuntu2]
gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu1]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.06-2ubuntu10]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.187.2+2.06-2ubuntu14 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10]
kbd/jammy-updates 2.3.0-3ubuntu4.22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.0-3ubuntu4]
libdrm-amdgpu1/jammy-updates 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.110-1ubuntu1]
libdrm-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2.4.110-1ubuntu1]
libdrm-intel1/jammy-updates 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.110-1ubuntu1]
libdrm-nouveau2/jammy-updates 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.110-1ubuntu1]
libdrm-radeon1/jammy-updates 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.110-1ubuntu1]
libdrm2/jammy-updates 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.110-1ubuntu1]
libegl-mesa0/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
libgbm1/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
libgl1-mesa-dri/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
libglapi-mesa/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
libglx-mesa0/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
libxatracker2/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
snapd/jammy-updates 2.58+22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.57.5+22.04ubuntu0.1]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
software-properties-gtk/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.13.2~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.9~22.04.1]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.192.54.3 all [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
update-notifier/jammy-updates 3.192.54.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
```

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces gnome-initial-setup gnome-remote-desktop grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed kbd libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-vulkan-drivers python3-software-properties snapd
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ubuntu-advantage-tools update-notifier update-notifier-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

I know I can issue a command to upgrade a specific package like: sudo apt upgrade snapd

On the other hand this does not sound very smart since on older ubuntu versions, a single upgrade command used to do the job.

Anybody knows what's going on?